# Trying to set up the SSD portion of an SSHD as a cache in Windows 7 but it appears to be doing nothing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I just installed Windows 7 on my laptop which has a hybrid drive. I put the OS on the hard disk drive portion and left the SSD part untouched, currently it’s just unallocated space. However I want to have the SSD act as a cache for the HDD to help speeds things up.

I installed Intel RST but theres no accelerate tab option. On second thoughts, I dont think intel RST is meant for SSHD systems, rather I think its meant for a HDD and a seperate SSD. Pls correct me if im wrong here.

I read on another forum where someone had the same problem, and a guy just said that on SSHDs the SSD automatically acts as a cache and therefore he didn’t have to do anything. *However*, when I access the computer management disk management tab, it shows me that the SSD is unallocated space and this causes me to think that the SSD portion is doing nothing.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is the make and model of the SSHD?

Answer (score 0):

You should not see two different drives, that is wrong.

According to [sevenforum](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/264512-fresh-install-windows-7-home-64bit-hybrid-ssd.html) you need to erase the drive properly and make sure isrt is set in the computer bios. Then the drive will show up as one composite when you install your os.

Read the article. Hope it helps!